# Ansible. Список ВМ-исключений

Tags: ansible

Всем привет!

Поднят Ansible для ВМ в vSphere с динамическим инвентарем, тэги пока не используем. Написано несколько ролей. Возникла необходимость исключить определенные ВМ из обработки плейбуками.
Для себя это вижу так: пишется дефолтная роль с main-таском, в котором указываем переменную со списком паттернов имен ВМ. Далее в таске указываем meta: end_host в том случае, если паттерн из переменной-списка содержится в имени ВМ.
После этого во все плейбуки в первых тасках импортируем дефолтную роль и необходимые ВМ пропускаются плейбуками.
Пробовал сделать так:

```
vars:
  exclusion_patterns:
    - mkr
    - vSphere
    - vyos
    - ovpn
    - pfSense
tasks:
  - name: End play for exclusion hosts
    meta: end_host
    when:
      - "{{ item }} in inventory_hostname"
    with_items: "{{ exclusion_patterns }}"
```

В таком случае при выполнении Ansible ругается на неопределенную переменную item. Пробовал вместо `{{ item }} in inventory_hostname` прописать `inventory_hostname | select('search',item) | list` (подсмотрел в интернетах), тоже не катит. Такое ощущение, что Ansible так не понимает, чего от него хотят.
Возможно ли вообще так сделать?
Указывать отдельный статический инвентарь со списком хостов исключений, а также указывать ограничения ключом `--limit` не хотелось бы, описанный мною выше вариант видится наиболее подходящим. Альтернативным вариантом вижу указание имен ВМ в исключениях при дискавери ВМ из vSphere.